# Getting "this operation is not authorized if the object is closed" error while doing an insert query from NodeJS

Tags: sql, node.js, ms-access

I'm using node-adodb to execute some queries to my access db. They all works fine except for one which is an insert. I'm getting the error mentioned in the title when I try to execute that one.
Here is the query I'm trying to execute :

```
                await connection.query("insert into Variants (CatalogCode,Variant,MeleePrice,StonePrice,RingPrice,PrRing,PrMelee,PrStone) values " +
                "('"+variantsToAdd[i].CatalogCode+"','"+variantsToAdd[i].Variant+"','"+variantsToAdd[i].MeleePrice+"','"+variantsToAdd[i].StonePrice+"','"
                +variantsToAdd[i].RingPrice+"','"+variantsToAdd[i].PrRing+"','"+variantsToAdd[i].PrMelee+"','"+variantsToAdd[i].PrStone+"')")
```

Since the other queries (select) are working I don't think the conncection to the db is the problem but here is the connection anyway :

```
const ADODB = require('node-adodb');
const connection = ADODB.open("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=\\\\HP-8000\\db\\db.accdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=xxx;")
```

Comment: Access does not want apostrophe delimiters for number or date/time type data. Apostrophes are for text type, # for date/time and nothing for number.

Comment: Are you able to try executing the query without `await`?

Comment: I corrected what @June7 said and it's still not working. I really don't understand why it's working for select but not for insert

Comment: Would a space on each side of + character help?

Comment: @June7 what do you mean by that ?

Comment: `"('" + variantsToAdd[i].CatalogCode + "'`.

Comment: @June7 oh ok, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Ok so this is starting to make less and less sense, because when i tried to do what @GordThompson suggested it actually worked. However this cause a problem because i want to do a loop of those query in order to insert a lot of rows

Comment: The Access "ACE" ODBC driver could well be somewhat limited in how it can handle concurrency on a single connection. The original Access "Jet" driver was written a *very long* time ago.